# Questions about details of @property in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, descriptor

Assume that I have a class as following:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.attr = value

    @property
    def attr(self):
        # This acts as a getter?
        # Let's call the function "attr_1" as alias
        return self.__attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        # This acts as a setter?
        # Let's call the function "attr_2" as alias
        self.__attr = value


inst = MyClass(1)
```

I read the [Documentation on Descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and looked at the implementation of `property` class.

As far as I know, when I type `inst.attr`, the following happens:

1. The first `attr` (whose alias is `attr_1`) is found, and `attr` is now an instance of `property` class, which is a **data descriptor**.
   Therefore, it will override the instance dictionary, which means `type(inst).__dict__['attr'].__get__(inst, type(inst))` is invoked.
2. `attr.__get__(inst, type(inst))` invokes `attr.fget(inst)`, where `fget()` is in fact the `attr(self)` (the "raw" `attr_1` function).
3. Finally, `attr.fget(inst)` returns `inst.__attr`.

---

- Here comes the first question: the class `MyClass` does not have an attribute `__attr`, then how to interpret `inst.__attr`in step 3?
- Similarly, in the emulated setter, how does Python find an attribute `inst.__attr` to assign the `value`?
- And a trivial question: since `property` is a class, why not `Property` instead of `property`?

Comment: `property` is actually considered a type, not a class (which are different things)

Comment: @thefourtheye the signature of `property` is `property(fget, fset, fdel, doc)` where the first three arguments are functions. The link to the documentation in the question shows a complete implementation of `property`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not directly related to properties actually, and the way they work as data descriptors. It's just the way Python fakes private attributes marked as starting with two underscores.

```
>>> inst.__attr

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    inst.__attr
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__attr'
```

Consider that you wrote your code using an internal variable with a single underscore (usually the convention to say, *you shouldn't touch this but I won't enforce, do at your own risk*):

```
>>> class MyClass2(object):

    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.attr = value

    @property
    def attr(self):
        # This acts as a getter?
        # Let's call the function "attr_1" as alias
        return self._attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        # This acts as a setter?
        # Let's call the function "attr_2" as alias
        self._attr = value


>>> inst2 = MyClass2(1)
>>> inst2._attr
1
```

And you can see the trick by peeking at the object's `__dict__`

```
>>> inst2.__dict__
{'_attr': 1}
>>> inst.__dict__
{'_MyClass__attr': 1}
```

Just some more to convince you that this has nothing to do with properties:

```
>>> class OtherClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__attr = value
    def get_attr(self):
        return self.__attr
    def set_attr(self, value):
        self.__attr = value


>>> other_inst = OtherClass(1)
>>> other_inst.get_attr()
1
>>> other_inst.__attr

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    other_inst.__attr
AttributeError: 'OtherClass' object has no attribute '__attr'
>>> other_inst.__dict__
{'_OtherClass__attr': 1}
>>> other_inst._OtherClass__attr
1
>>> other_inst._OtherClass__attr = 24
>>> other_inst.get_attr()
24
>>> inst._MyClass__attr = 23
>>> inst.attr
23
```

Concerning your last question, I just don't think there is such a convention in Python that classes must start with an uppercase. `property` is not an isolated case (`datetime`, `itemgetter`, `csv.reader`, ...).

Comment: Thank you. I tried you example code and found that `self.attr` and `self._attr` are exactly the same object (`inst.attr is inst._attr` returns `True`). Why does it happen? And would not it be confusing when we define two variables and one of which is "protected" (at least it is deemed to be "protected by convention) but in fact they are the same object?

Comment: They are not the same attribute. What they hold is however the same object. This is what you are testing when typing ``inst.attr is inst._attr``. It's like ``a = c; b = c; a is b``.

Comment: @Zelong Your second question happens only because the example is too simple. You would not want a property for that. A more complex but more accurate example would be a class that holds a point in 2D, with x and y attributes, and say that you want a ``coordinates`` property that returns a tuple containing x and y. You could also define a setter that extract x and y from a 2-tuple. The deleter would delete both x and y. According to your needs, x and y can be accessed directly, or maybe you'll want to hide them (In Python you are not supposed to hide anyway).